# How to create config to be used by vim init.lua?

Tags: neovim, init.lua

I am going to write my nvim config in lua. I want to use this config on several computers. And vim configuration on these computers should be slightly different. For example, on some installations I want plugin X to be installed, but on others - not.

So I want to create some installation-specific file in ~/.config/nvim. Kind of config file for my vim config. (and no, I will not go deeper). As this file is different on different installations I will not commit it, but rest of lua configuration scripts will read it and act accordingly.

What format is most appropriate for this file? For example, if I make it yaml, will it be possible to open and parse it from init.lua ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using a separate YAML file, one option is to just use Lua directly. Use simple Lua syntax to populate a Lua table from your local config file.

Perhaps something like:

```
localconfig = {}
dofile(os.getenv("HOME") .. "/.config/nvim/localconfig.lua")
```

And then in file `~/.config/nvim/localconfig.lua` you can add:

```
localconfig.setting1 = "value1"
localconfig.setting2 = 2
localconfig.setting3 = {4, 9, 16}
```

etc.

You can initialize `localconfig` in your `init.lua` with defaults before you load the overrides.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [lua-yaml](https://luarocks.org/modules/dominicletz/lua-yaml) to parse Yaml files from Lua.

Or use the Lua binding to LibYAML [lyaml](https://github.com/gvvaughan/lyaml)

Comment: But to use these packages I need to install them first. How do I install any of these packages in such a way that lua interpreter built into nvim would be able to use them? If I simply white `require('yaml')` in my lua.init I just get an error: module 'yaml' not found

Comment: I suppose you can catch the exception raise by requires and launch the `LuaRocks` command: `LuaRocks install lua-yaml`

Comment: I guess LuaRocks would install package for system lua. I highly doubt that the lua interpreter built into vim would be able to use it. Anyway, I do not have LuaRocks installed, and lua could be not installed on the system at all.